# Maximum call stack size exceeded raises when I invoke this.constructor.superclass.someMethod

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am learning javascript.
I have found out popular extend function:

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}
```

Lets create 3 classes

```
function foo() {}
foo.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I'm a foo";
}

function bar() {}
extend(bar, foo)
bar.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I'm a bar and " +
        this.constructor.superclass.identify.apply(this, arguments);
}

function zot() {}
extend(zot, bar)
zot.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I'm a zot and " +
        this.constructor.superclass.identify.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Thus we have following inhertitance sheme:

```
foo->bar->zot
```

Lets write some code:

```
f = new foo();

alert(f.identify()); // "I'm a foo"

b = new bar();

alert(b.identify()); // "I'm a bar and I'm a foo"

z = new zot();

alert(z.identify()); // stack overflow
```

Lost row produces

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)
```

Can you explain what happens in details?

Answer (score 0):

Because once `identify.apply(this)` is being called twice (like in `zot` and unlike in `bar`), `this` would point to the same instance on both functions and will call its own `identify()` method endlessly.

Instead, try to explicitly point to the base `identify` method:

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
  var F = function() {}
  F.prototype = Parent.prototype
  Child.prototype = new F()
  Child.prototype.constructor = Child
  Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}

function foo() {}
foo.prototype.identify = function() {
  return "I'm a foo";
}

function bar() {}
extend(bar, foo)
bar.prototype.identify = function() {
  return "I'm a bar and " +
    bar.superclass.identify.apply(this, arguments);
}

function zot() {}
extend(zot, bar)
zot.prototype.identify = function() {
  return "I'm a zot and " +
    zot.superclass.identify.apply(this, arguments);
}

var f = new foo();
alert(f.identify()); // "I'm a foo"

var b = new bar();
alert(b.identify()); // "I'm a bar and I'm a foo"

var z = new zot();
alert(z.identify()); // "I'm a zot and I'm a bar and I'm a foo"
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj7wcyof/3/)